Proof verification and ideas: A set of all ordered pairs does not exist.
Context:
I am currently reading Herbert Enderton’s “Set theory” along with Terrence Tao’s “Analysis I”. While reading the chapter on Relations and Functions,  I came across this question. I have searched answers for this question and found this on MSE. But I have different approaches to this problem from those discussed in that thread. What makes my question different is

I have shown my approach towards the problem and I request verifications, corrections and solutions (if my approaches are wrong)
I request for a proof that purely relies on sets, relations and Cartesian products in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Claim: A set of all ordered pairs does not exist.
Proof: Assume that such a set exists. Then, for any $a$ and $b$ we can form the set $S=\{ \langle a, b\rangle \}$, where $\langle a, b\rangle =\{ \{a\},  \{a, b\}\}$ (Kuratowski definition). By the union axiom, $\bigcup\bigcup S=\{a, b\}$. But for any $a$,  $a\in \{a, b\}\in \bigcup\bigcup S=\Omega$. (The universal set is denoted $\Omega$ in Tao’s Analysis). Then $\forall  a\in \Omega$. Hence,  $\Omega$ is the universal set, which doesn’t exist by the axiom of regularity. $\blacksquare$
The problem with this proof is, (I guess) that it is quite “unaxiomatic and informal ”, since at the beginning when we assume for “any $a$ and $b$”, we indirectly assume the existence of a universal set.
Maybe another proof would be constructing a set of ordered pairs and claiming it to have all of them and then constructing another set having more ordered pairs than the latter. (I have the feeling that this could go on as an infinite loop). Here is my sketch of the proof:
Proof: (Informal)
By utilizing the subset axiom we can construct a set $S=\{\langle a, b\rangle : a, b\in X\}$, where $X$ is a non-empty set. Then by union and regularity, $X\cup \{X\}$ would be a set. Again by the subset axiom, we construct a set $S’=\{\langle a, b\rangle : a, b\in X\cup \{X\}\}$. It is quite easy to see that $S\subset S’$ (but I don’t know how to prove this fact). Hence $S’$ contains elements (here, ordered pairs) that are not in $S$ (by the definition of a proper subset).  $\blacksquare$
My Questions

Are my observations correct?
If yes, how can I make the proofs rigorous? (To be precise, I don’t know how to prove $S\subset S’$), so can anyone help me with that?
If my proofs are wrong, are there any other ways to prove this without invoking classes and functions? (The reason being that I am still unfamiliar with them as they come after these topics)…

Being a newcomer to this forum, I would value any constructive feedbacks or suggestions related to my questions, approaches or thinking.
Edit: I would like to see alternative proofs to this claim.

Your first proof is fine (for “any $a$ and $b$” [in the universe] does not "assume the existence of a universal set"). The second one is non-conclusive, and not even right if $X\in X$.

@AnneBauval Can you explain how?? Which step in the proof is wrong??

If $X\in X$ then $X\cup {X}=X$ hence $S'=S$.

@AnneBauval But $X\in X$ is not allowed in $\mathsf{ZFC}$... Precisely by the axiom of regularity...

It is well-known that the axiom of regularity forbids $X\in X$, but this axiom is often considered as additional, not belonging to ZFC. Anyway, even if $S\subsetneq S'$, this doesn't prove what you wanted.

@Anne Bauval Yes of course!!

@AnneBauval But why proving $S\subsetneq S'$ doesn't prove my claim?? We are just showing that elements in $S'$ are not in $S$..

And this doesn't prove that there is no set of all ordered pairs. Btw, my first comment was too hasty. Your first proof has the right idea but is not correctly written. Your $S$ should be the set of all $\langle a, b\rangle$s, not just one of them.

@AnneBauval Can you formulate you views and ideas as an answer?? It would be helpful for me...


Nothing is wrong in your "informal proof" (assuming the axiom of regularity, or at least $X\notin X$) but it doesn't reach the goal. You only associated, to each set $X$, two sets $S\subsetneq S'$. This doesn't prove the non-existence of a set of all ordered pairs.
Your first proof is standard (I can see no need of alternative proofs), provided you rewrite it correctly: your $S$ should be the set of all $⟨a,b⟩$s, not just one of them: assume there is a set $S$ of all ordered pairs [of sets] (Kuratowski-coded by: $⟨a,b⟩:=\{ \{a\},  \{a, b\}\}$). Then, $\cup S$ is the set of all singletons and pairs [of sets], hence $\cup\cup S$ is the set of all sets: contradiction.


Since we assume that $S$ is the set containing all ordered pairs and we prove that $S'$ has "some more" ordered pairs (since we take $a$ and $b$ from a larger set) so we can conclude $S$ is not the set of all ordered pairs. I don't see an error here.

Can't $X$ be a set in the universe of discourse??

In your "informal proof", you are not assuming that $S$ is the set of all ordered pairs. Only all ordered pairs of elements of some set $X$ (which is not the whole universe since the latter is not a set).

Can't we assume a set large enough or for any $a$ and $b$?? Would that make it similar to the first one??

I edited my previous comment. And if you take $X=$ the whole universe then $S$ is as in the standard proof (the set of all ordered pairs), but you cannot use the axiom $X\notin X$ since $X$ not a set.

@Anne Bauval OK, in the first proof how do you write the set $S$ in set builder form?? Can you help me with this??

@Akash A set that large would become a class, which you have mentioned to be avoided in your question. Also, classes are not allowed in $ \mathsf{ZFC}$.

@Math_analyst_108 I cannot write $S$ in set builder form since it would prove it is a set. The best I can write (reasoning by contradiction) is $$(\forall a)(\forall b){{a},{a,b}}\in S$$ or just $$(\forall a)(\exists c\in S){a}\in c,$$ which will entail $$(\forall a){a}\in\cup S$$ hence $$(\forall a)a\in\cup\cup S.$$

@AnneBauval Thank you!!

@Math_analyst_108 I don't understand your comment to Akash "...a class, which you have mentioned to be avoided in your question", as the question was yours.
